# finding a way to use f:ajax tag to load a link on initial page load

Tags: ajax, jsf

i am new to using the f:ajax tag and jsf.I have been able to use this tag to place a link on my page when a change event occurs with h:selectOneMenu tag. But now  i want the  link to be placed when the page loads initially i.e using my listener method to check if the current value of h:selectonemenue fulfills reason to display the link whenever the page loads initially.Thank you in anticipation of an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you could use the following script together with a hidden commandLink to invoke your ajax listener:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       $('hiddenGlobal\\:link').onclick();
    });
</script>
<h:form id="hiddenGlobal" style="display:none">
        <h:commandLink id="link">
            <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{yourBean.yourListener}"/>
        </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

If you are not on jQuery, you could use `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('hiddenGlobal:link').onclick();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> *But now i want the link to be placed when the page loads initially i.e using my listener method to check if the current value of h:selectonemenue fulfills reason to display the link whenever the page loads initially*

Just use the `rendered` attribute.

```
<h:link ... rendered="#{bean.selectOneMenuValue == 'desiredValue'}" />
```